# Zoom On Web View

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I have a html document's webView Show me how I can enable zoom in webView??

My Code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/police_gozarname.html");
```

Comment: wthin 1 minute. same answer given from three user lollss.

Answer (score 0):

please try this snippet.

```
 webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Type below line before you load your webview.

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable built in zoom controls by:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```